# How to check out communityreputationsettings.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, check-out, community-site

I'm trying to change the Reputaion Settings on a community site.
When I click OK after selecting the settings I get a 'Something Went Wrong' error message telling me to check out the document before edditing it.

I'm not editting a document, I'm changing site settings!

Has anyone encountered this problem before and is there a known workaround. Google has failed me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. I manage to solve it.

To change the Reputation Settings you have to:

1. Checkout all pages in SitePages library
2. Do the change in Reputaion Settings
3. Check in the pages from SitePages library